# Python + GTK: How to set a selected row on gtk.treeview

Tags: python, gtk, gtktreeview

I'm trying to do a keyboard command. When I insert <kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>some_number</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> I need call a function that will see this number on a column on `Gtk.Treeview` and set that row has selected. How can I do that?

Comment: can you connect a `key-press-event` to the treeview and use the connected function to build up a search-string until you recieve a Return? Then `ts = treeveiw.get_selection()` should give you a selection-object for the treeview and `ts.select_path(path)`, where path is a proper path according to the input and the structure of your tree-model, should mark the right stuff. I'm not sure though and since I don't have code to test it on...

Comment: Great... should have written it as an answer then..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<treeview>.set_cursor(0)  # for your value of `path` 0
```

is this what you want?
I think treeview will also grab focus.

If you wanted to add given row to selection set rather than clear old selection and set only one row selected, you gotta play with `Gtk.TreeSelection` that you get via `.get_selection()` method.