# Getting the Gtk.TreePath of the first row in a Gtk.TreeView

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I want to have the first row of a `Gtk.TreeView` selected upon a button press. I'm aware that this is possible using `row_activated`, however `row_activated` takes a `Gtk.TreePath` and a `Gtk.TreeViewColumn` (which I assume can be set to `None`). The issue is that I do not know how to get the `Gtk.TreePath` of the first row.

```
class Main(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str)
        liststore.append(['first_entry'])
        liststore.append(['second_entry'])
        liststore.append(['third_entry'])

        treeview = Gtk.TreeView()
        treeview.set_model(liststore)

        renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Item', renderer, text=0)
        treeview.append_column(column)

        button = Gtk.Button(label='button')

        box = Gtk.Box()
        box.set_orientation(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        box.add(button)
        box.add(treeview)
        
        self.add(box)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    main.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

In this case, when the button is pressed,  I want `first_entry` (which is the first row) to be selected

Comment: you could create minimal working code so we could use it for solutions.

Comment: my bad, just added it

Comment: it seems `row_activated` is event which is generated AFTER row was selected - so it can be too late, and it is not for selecting row. I found `treeview.set_cursor(0)` in question: [Python + GTK: How to set a selected row on gtk.treeview - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945381/python-gtk-how-to-set-a-selected-row-on-gtk-treeview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found `treeview.set_cursor(0)` in question: [Python + GTK: How to set a selected row on gtk.treeview - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945381/python-gtk-how-to-set-a-selected-row-on-gtk-treeview) and I think it can be better solution.

BTW: you have to use `self.` to access `treeview` in function executed by button.

```
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Main(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str)
        liststore.append(['first_entry'])
        liststore.append(['second_entry'])
        liststore.append(['third_entry'])

        self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView()
        self.treeview.set_model(liststore)

        renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
       
        column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Item', renderer, text=0)
        self.treeview.append_column(column)

        button = Gtk.Button(label='button')
        button.connect('clicked', self.select_first)
        
        box = Gtk.Box()
        box.set_orientation(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        box.add(button)
        box.add(self.treeview)
        
        self.add(box)

    def select_first(self, event):
        self.treeview.set_cursor(0)
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    main.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Doc for [set_cursor()](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeView.html#Gtk.TreeView.set_cursor) for C/C++ (but can be useful).

It seems original `set_cursor()` also needs `TreePath` but in Python it works with `index`. Other functions don't have to work with `index` instead of `TreePath`

---

**EDIT:**

I found you can create `TreePath` using `index` - as `list` or `string`

```
def select_first(self, event):
    path = Gtk.TreePath.new_from_indices([0]) # it needs list because trees can be nestes, ie. [0,5,3]
    #path = Gtk.TreePath.new_from_string("0")  # for nested trees it can be ie. "0:5:3"

    selection = self.treeview.get_selection()

    selection.select_path(path)
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you use `self.` when you create `self.column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Item', renderer, text=0)` then you can use it with `row_activated()` but this doesn't select row on my computer (but doesn't raise error)

```
def select_first(self, event):
    path = Gtk.TreePath.new_from_indices([0])
    self.treeview.row_activated(path, self.column)
```

---

Full code which I used for tests:

```
# https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeSelection.html#gtk-treeselection
# https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TreePath.html#Gtk.TreePath.new_from_indices

import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Main(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
        
        liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str)
        liststore.append(['first_entry'])
        liststore.append(['second_entry'])
        liststore.append(['third_entry'])

        self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView()
        self.treeview.set_model(liststore)

        renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
       
        self.column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Item', renderer, text=0)
        self.treeview.append_column(self.column)

        button1 = Gtk.Button(label='First')
        button1.connect('clicked', self.select_first)

        button2 = Gtk.Button(label='Second')
        button2.connect('clicked', self.select_second)

        button3 = Gtk.Button(label='Third')
        button3.connect('clicked', self.select_third)

        box = Gtk.Box()
        box.set_orientation(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        box.add(button1)
        box.add(button2)
        box.add(button3)
        box.add(self.treeview)
        
        self.add(box)

    def select_first(self, event):
        self.treeview.set_cursor(0)
        
    def select_second(self, event):
        path = Gtk.TreePath.new_from_indices([1])  # it needs list because trees can be nestes, ie. [0,5,3]
        path = Gtk.TreePath.new_from_string("1")   # for nested trees it can be ie. "0:5:3"
        selection = self.treeview.get_selection()
        selection.select_path(path)  
        
    def select_third(self, event):
        path = Gtk.TreePath.new_from_indices([2])  # it needs list because trees can be nestes, ie. [0,5,3]
        self.treeview.row_activated(path, self.column)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    main.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I really appreciate it. This solves the problem completely.